# Draw lines in iOS storyboard similar to Android's XML lines

Tags: ios, uiview, line, uistoryboard

In Android I can draw lines by simple creating a view and setting its background color

```
<LinearLayout...>
...
<View android:layout_width="1dp"
  android:layout_height="match_parent"
  android:background="@color/black"
...
<View android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="2dp"
  android:background="@color/red"
...
</LinearLayout>
```

This is a common practice in Android. How might I do the same in iOS? What's the common practice? I see another question here trying to ask a similar question but was told to use a TableView. I am looking for something as simple and as general as the Android answer.

Comment: I see the down vote. But I didn't want to assume the android answer was the iOS answer: as I am discovering iOS is a lot more friendly and complete than android is -- to put it mildly.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You can create a generic `UIView` and set its `width` or `height` to 1 pt in a storyboard. Set its `backgroundColor` to what you want the line to be. Make sure you set its constraints or resizing mask so that it doesn't grow in width/height when the screen is resized.

Answer (score 9):

```
 UIView *lineView = [[UIView alloc]init];
 lineView.frame = CGRectMake(0,50,self.View.frame.size.width,1);
 lineView.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];
 [self.view addSubview:lineView];
```

Take this simple view created in code and just adjust its height by 1 or 2 
Just like in the above code -> lineView.frame =CGRectMake(<#CGFloat x#>, <#CGFloat y#>, <#CGFloat width#>, <#CGFloat height#>);
CGFloat height is taken is 1

Answer (score 4):

The same exact thing. Use a `UIView` with a small width and set its background color to the desired color.

Answer (score 1):

// to draw line in uiview class

```
 CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
 CGContextSetLineWidth(context, 1.0);
 CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(context, [[UIColor whiteColor]   CGColor]);
 CGContextMoveToPoint(context, xstartPoint, yStart);
 CGContextAddLineToPoint(context, xstartPoint, yBottom);
 CGContextStrokePath(context);
 CGContextSaveGState(context);
```

Comment: This needs explanation. Presumably this code goes in `drawRect:` method of your custom subclass of UIView.